Draw 3 dimensional ring
Can you help to draw this figure?
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{circuitikz}
        %upper ring
        \draw[fill=yellow](0,0) ellipse(2 cm and .7 cm);
        \draw[fill=white](0,0) ellipse(1.67 cm and .5 cm);
        
        \def\d{1.5}
        \draw(2,0)--++(0,-\d) coordinate(X1);
        \draw(-2,0)--++(0,-\d) coordinate(X2);
        
        \draw (X1) arc(0:-180:2cm and .6cm);
        
        
        
        %lower ring
        
            \draw[fill=yellow](0,-4) ellipse(2 cm and .7 cm);
        \draw[fill=white](0,-4) ellipse(1.67 cm and .5 cm);
        
        \def\d{1.95}
        \draw(2,-4)--++(0,-\d) coordinate(X1a);
        \draw(-2,-4)--++(0,-\d) coordinate(X2a);
        
        \draw (X1a) arc(0:-180:2cm and .6cm);
        
        \foreach\y in{-4.1,-4.15, ..., -5.9} \draw(2,\y) arc(0:-180: 2cm and .6cm);
        
        
        %the cylinder 
        \draw[fill=yellow](0,3) ellipse(1.3 cm and .5 cm);
        \def\d{11}
        \draw(1.3,3)--++(0,-\d) coordinate(X1);
        \draw(-1.3,3)--++(0,-\d) coordinate(X2);
        
        \draw (X1) arc(0:-180:1.3cm and .5cm);
        
     
     %circuit
     
     \draw(2,-4.5)--(2.7,-4.5)--++(0,1.5)--++(.5,0)--++(.8,.3);
     
\draw(2,-5.5)--(2.7,-5.5)--++(0,-1.5)--++(1,0);
        
        
        \coordinate(K1)at(5,-3);
        \coordinate(K0)at(5,-5);
        \coordinate(K2)at(5,-7);
        
        \draw(K1)to[battery] (K0);
        \draw(K0)to[battery] (K2);
        \draw(K1)--++(-.9,0);
        \draw(K2)--++(-1.3,0);
        
        %labels
\scriptsize     
    \draw(-2.3,2)node[left] {ferrous core}--++(1,-.2);
    \draw(-2.6,0)node[left] {aluminium ring}--++(.7,-.2);
    \draw(-2.6,-5)node[left] {coil of insulated wire}--++(.7,-.2);

    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}



UPDATE 2:
Monochrome version too but retaining the forced metallic shades.
U2 RESULT:

U2 MWE:
\documentclass[border=3.14pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\alt{0.55}
        \def\Ring#1#2#3#4#5[#6]{%\Ring{position}{Radious}{widht}{height}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
                \coordinate (#6--east) at (0:#2);
                \coordinate (#6--west) at (180:#2);
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
                    \fill[fill=#5,even odd rule]
                        (0:#2)
                            arc (0:180:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                            -- (180:#2-#3) 
                            arc (180:0:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \fill[draw,fill=#5]
                        (0:#2-#3)
                            arc (0:180:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            --++(0,-#4)
                            arc (180:0:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            -- cycle;
                    \draw[black](0:#2) arc (0:180:#2 and #2*\alt);
                    \draw[black](0:#2-#3) arc (0:180:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \foreach \r in {45,135}{%forced radial shade
                        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=20}] in {0,2,...,20}{
                            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                            (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)  -- (\r-\s+\i:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt) -- cycle;
                        }
                    }                  
                \end{pgfonlayer}
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}
                    \fill[fill=#5,even odd rule]
                    (180-1:#2)
                        arc (180-1:360+1:#2 and #2*\alt)
                        -- (360+1:#2-#3)
                        arc (360+1:180-1:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \fill[fill=#5]
                    (0:#2)
                        arc (360:180:#2 and #2*\alt)
                        --++(0,-#4)
                        arc (180:360:#2 and #2*\alt)
                        -- cycle;
                    \draw[black]
                        (0:#2)
                            --++(0,-#4)
                            arc (360:180:#2 and #2*\alt)
                            --++(0,#4);
                    \draw[black](180-1:#2) arc (180-1:360+1:#2 and #2*\alt);
                    \draw[black](180-1:#2-#3) arc (180-1:360+1:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \foreach \r in {-45,-135}{%forced radial shade
                        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=20}] in {0,2,...,20}{
                            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                            (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)  -- (\r-\s+\i:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt) -- cycle;
                        }
                    }
                    \foreach \r in {-45,-90}{%forced radial side shade
                        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=20}] in {0,2,...,20}{
                            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                            (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)-- ++(0,-#4) arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) -- cycle;
                        }
                    }
                \end{pgfonlayer}    
            \end{scope}
            
        }
        
        \def\cilinder#1#2#3#4[#5]{%\cilinder{position}{Radious}{height}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
                \coordinate (#5--east) at (0:#2);
                \coordinate (#5--west) at (180:#2);
                \fill[draw,fill=#4] (0:#2) arc (0:180:#2 and #2*\alt) -- ++ (0,-#3) arc (180:360:#2 and #2*\alt) -- cycle;
                \draw[black](0:#2) arc (0:360:#2 and #2*\alt);
                \foreach \r in {135,45,-45,-135}{%forced radial shade
                    \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=20}] in {0,2,...,20}{
                        \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                        (0,0) -- (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                        arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)-- cycle;
                    }
                }
                \foreach \r in {-85,-135}{%forced radial side shade
                    \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=20}] in {0,2,...,20}{
                        \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                        (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                        arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)-- ++(0,-#3) arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) -- cycle;
                    }
                }
            \end{scope}
        }
        
        %The metals
        \cilinder{0,0}{1}{5}{white}[A]
        \Ring{0,-1}{1.8}{0.5}{1}{white}[B]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,18}{%Generate 18 named rings from CuRing-1 to CuRing-18
            \Ring{0,-4.5+0.06*\i}{1.1}{0.1}{0mm}{white}[C\i]
        }
        
        %The circuit
        \draw
        (C14--east)%From te coordinate east of CuRing-14
            -| ++(1,1)% Squared path first horizontal then vertical to x+1 and y+1 from previous coordinate (x,y)
            to [nos] ++(2,0)%Normal Open Switch from previous coordinate (x',y') to (x'+2,y'+0)
            to [battery] ++ (0,-1.4)
            to [battery] ++ (0,-1.4)
            -- ++ (-2,0)
            |- (C2--east);
        
        %labels
        \scriptsize
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}    
            \draw($(A--west)+(0.5,0)$) -- ++(-1,0.5)node[left] {ferrous core};
            \draw($(B--west)+(0.25,0)$) -- ++(-1.2,0.5)node[left] {Aluminium ring};
            \draw($(C18--west)+(0.07,0)$) -- ++(-1,0.5)node[left] {Coil of insulated wire};
        \end{pgfonlayer}     
                   
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}

UPDATE:
This is the option with white fills only.
U-RESULT:

U-MWE:
\documentclass[border=3.14pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\alt{0.55}
        \def\Ring#1#2#3#4#5[#6]{%\Ring{position}{Radious}{widht}{height}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
                \coordinate (#6--east) at (0:#2);
                \coordinate (#6--west) at (180:#2);
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
                    \fill[fill=#5,even odd rule]
                        (0:#2)
                            arc (0:180:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                            -- (180:#2-#3) 
                            arc (180:0:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \fill[draw,fill=#5]
                        (0:#2-#3)
                            arc (0:180:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            --++(0,-#4)
                            arc (180:0:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            -- cycle;
                    \draw[black](0:#2) arc (0:180:#2 and #2*\alt);
                    \draw[black](0:#2-#3) arc (0:180:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);                  
                \end{pgfonlayer}
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}
                    \fill[fill=#5,even odd rule]
                    (180-1:#2)
                        arc (180-1:360+1:#2 and #2*\alt)
                        -- (360+1:#2-#3)
                        arc (360+1:180-1:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \fill[fill=#5]
                    (0:#2)
                        arc (360:180:#2 and #2*\alt)
                        --++(0,-#4)
                        arc (180:360:#2 and #2*\alt)
                        -- cycle;
                    \draw[black]
                        (0:#2)
                            --++(0,-#4)
                            arc (360:180:#2 and #2*\alt)
                            --++(0,#4);
                    \draw[black](180-1:#2) arc (180-1:360+1:#2 and #2*\alt);
                    \draw[black](180-1:#2-#3) arc (180-1:360+1:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                \end{pgfonlayer}    
            \end{scope}
            
        }
        
        \def\cilinder#1#2#3#4[#5]{%\cilinder{position}{Radious}{height}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
                \coordinate (#5--east) at (0:#2);
                \coordinate (#5--west) at (180:#2);
                \fill[draw,fill=#4] (0:#2) arc (0:180:#2 and #2*\alt) -- ++ (0,-#3) arc (180:360:#2 and #2*\alt) -- cycle;
                \draw[black](0:#2) arc (0:360:#2 and #2*\alt);
            \end{scope}
        }
        
        %The metals
        \cilinder{0,0}{1}{5}{white}[A]
        \Ring{0,-1}{1.8}{0.5}{1}{white}[B]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,18}{%Generate 18 named rings from CuRing-1 to CuRing-18
            \Ring{0,-4.5+0.06*\i}{1.1}{0.1}{0mm}{white}[C\i]
        }
        
        %The circuit
        \draw
        (C14--east)%From te coordinate east of CuRing-14
            -| ++(1,1)% Squared path first horizontal then vertical to x+1 and y+1 from previous coordinate (x,y)
            to [nos] ++(2,0)%Normal Open Switch from previous coordinate (x',y') to (x'+2,y'+0)
            to [battery] ++ (0,-1.4)
            to [battery] ++ (0,-1.4)
            -- ++ (-2,0)
            |- (C2--east);
        
        %labels
        \scriptsize
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}    
            \draw($(A--west)+(0.5,0)$) -- ++(-1,0.5)node[left] {ferrous core};
            \draw($(B--west)+(0.25,0)$) -- ++(-1.2,0.5)node[left] {Aluminium ring};
            \draw($(C18--west)+(0.07,0)$) -- ++(-1,0.5)node[left] {Coil of insulated wire};
        \end{pgfonlayer}     
                   
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}

Well, you practically drew everything, what remains to be resolved is how to make it displayed as 3D objects, well for that it is necessary to work with 2 additional layers, one for objects behind and another for objects in front, then since it is about metals I added all the types of shades available that I have, to avoid having to repeat everything, I grouped it into 2 drawing objects, which are the ring and the cylinder, After some trial and error I fixed them so that you can draw them in a specific position with a given radius, width, length, color, and name, that way I can apply the shades to all the objects without having to type everything again, and since the ring is in the front and back layers, and the cylinder in the default layer, they give the impression that the cylinder passes through the middle of the ring, there is a variable \alt, with which you can modify the height of the apparent 3D view.
RESULT:

MWE: (note: the compilation may take a few extra seconds than usual, this is due to iterating the forced shades many times)
\documentclass[border=3.14pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}
\definecolor{cooper}{HTML}{CC9671}
\definecolor{aluminium}{HTML}{F1F1F2}
\definecolor{iron}{HTML}{646464}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\alt{0.55}
        \def\Ring#1#2#3#4#5[#6]{%\Ring{position}{Radious}{widht}{height}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
                \coordinate (#6--east) at (0:#2);
                \coordinate (#6--west) at (180:#2);
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
                    \shade[left color=#5,even odd rule](0:#2) arc (0:180:#2 and #2*\alt) -- (180:#2-#3) arc (180:0:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \shade[draw,right color=black,left color=#5]
                        (0:#2-#3)
                            arc (0:180:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            --++(0,-#4)
                            arc (180:0:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            -- cycle;
                    \draw[black](0:#2) arc (0:180:#2 and #2*\alt);
                    \draw[black](0:#2-#3) arc (0:180:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \foreach \r in {45,135}{%forced radial shade
                        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=30}] in {0,2,...,30}{
                            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                            (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)  -- (\r-\s+\i:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt) -- cycle;
                        }
                    }                   
                \end{pgfonlayer}
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}
                    \shade[left color=#5,even odd rule]
                    (180-1:#2)
                        arc (180-1:360+1:#2 and #2*\alt)
                        -- (360+1:#2-#3)
                        arc (360+1:180-1:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \shade[draw,left color=black!60!#5,middle color=#5,right color=#5!50!white]
                    (0:#2)
                        arc (360:180:#2 and #2*\alt)
                        --++(0,-#4)
                        arc (180:360:#2 and #2*\alt)
                        -- cycle;
                    \draw[black](180-1:#2) arc (180-1:360+1:#2 and #2*\alt);
                    \draw[black](180-1:#2-#3) arc (180-1:360+1:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt);
                    \foreach \r in {-45,-135}{%forced radial shade
                        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=30}] in {0,2,...,30}{
                            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                            (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)  -- (\r-\s+\i:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt)
                            arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:#2-#3 and #2*\alt-#3*\alt) -- cycle;
                        }
                    }
                    \foreach \r in {-45,-90}{%forced radial side shade
                        \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=30}] in {0,2,...,30}{
                            \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                            (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                            arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)-- ++(0,-#4) arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) -- cycle;
                        }
                    }
                \end{pgfonlayer}    
            \end{scope}

        }
        
        \def\cilinder#1#2#3#4[#5]{%\cilinder{position}{Radious}{height}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
                \coordinate (#5--east) at (0:#2);
                \coordinate (#5--west) at (180:#2);
                \shade[draw,left color=black!60!#4,middle color=#4,right color=#4!50!white] (0:#2) arc (0:180:#2 and #2*\alt) -- ++ (0,-#3) arc (180:360:#2 and #2*\alt) -- cycle;
                \shade[draw,left color=#4](0:#2) arc (0:360:#2 and #2*\alt);
                \foreach \r in {135,45,-45,-135}{%forced radial shade
                    \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=30}] in {0,2,...,30}{
                        \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                        (0,0) -- (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                        arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)-- cycle;
                    }
                }
                \foreach \r in {-85,-135}{%forced radial side shade
                    \foreach \i [evaluate={\s=30}] in {0,2,...,30}{
                        \fill [black, fill opacity=1/50] 
                        (\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) 
                        arc (\r+\s-\i:\r-\s+\i:#2 and #2*\alt)-- ++(0,-#3) arc (\r-\s+\i:\r+\s-\i:#2 and #2*\alt) -- cycle;
                    }
                }
                
            \end{scope}
        }
        
        %The metals
        \cilinder{0,0}{1}{5}{iron}[FeCore-1]
        \Ring{0,-1}{1.8}{0.5}{1}{aluminium}[AlRing-1]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,18}{%Generate 18 named rings from CuRing-1 to CuRing-18
            \Ring{0,-4.5+0.06*\i}{1.1}{0.1}{0mm}{cooper}[CuRing-\i]
        }
            
        %The circuit
        \draw
        (CuRing-14--east)%From te coordinate east of CuRing-14
            -| ++(1,1)% Squared path first horizontal then vertical to x+1 and y+1 from previous coordinate (x,y)
            to [nos] ++(2,0)%Normal Open Switch from previous coordinate (x',y') to (x'+2,y'+0)
            to [battery] ++ (0,-1.4)
            to [battery] ++ (0,-1.4)
            -- ++ (-2,0)
            |- (CuRing-2--east);
    
        %labels
        \scriptsize
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground layer}    
        \draw($(FeCore-1--west)+(0.5,0)$) -- ++(-1,0.5)node[left] {ferrous core};
        \draw($(AlRing-1--west)+(0.25,0)$) -- ++(-1.2,0.5)node[left] {Aluminium ring};
        \draw($(CuRing-18--west)+(0.07,0)$) -- ++(-1,0.5)node[left] {Coil of insulated wire};
        \end{pgfonlayer}        
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}


Can you Leon give a result with minimum shading, for black and white printing only?

Yours is beautiful for colour printing.

@Epa, I added more options.
